# Golang custom package is not found

Tags: go, import, package, goland

I created custom package and I want to use it externally

My package directory structure is like this:

GOPATH:

```
- src/
  - program/
    - new_package/
      - tool.go
```

And I want to add it to other Go program:

```
import "program/new_package"
```

But then I got this error from Goland - package
XXXX is not in GOROOT

Goland finds the package by default. My GOPATH is set to standard directory and I don't know what's the problem ...

P.S. I am not using GO modules in this case

Comment: Package import paths need to be of the form "domain.com/whatever", e.g. "github.com/you/yourmodule/yourpackage". A package without a domain is assumed to be part of the standard library (hence why it's looking in GOROOT).

Comment: [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) covers all of this in detail.

Comment: @Adrian that's just a recommendation isn't it? The paths don't actually *need* to be of that form (https://imgur.com/a/3yphI8m). Or is that like a GoLand specific requirement?

Comment: @Adrian: modules and GOPATH imports both work locally just fine without a domain name, they just are not publicly discoverable.

Comment: Interesting - must just be something I've told myself after solving something ages ago. Good to know.